# Android NDK passing long values to native method

Tags: android, parameters, android-ndk, native, long-integer

This is my function:

```
Long Java_my_package_MainActivity_getDistance(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, Long a_id1,Long a_id2)
    {
        char temp[128];
        sprintf(temp,"ID1: %u , ID2: %u",a_id1, a_id2);
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "From NDK : ", temp);
        return(0);//just to test ... 
    }
```

Long is a type def:

```
typedef long long Long;
```

because i have some values that are grater than the max value of int type

in my java class:

```
 static {
            System.loadLibrary("module"); 
        }
        // declare the native code function - must match ndkfoo.c
    private native int getDistance(long id1, long id2);
```

I call the native function with this line:

```
getDistance(1234,2456);
```

the output in the logcat is:

```
ID1: 1234, ID2: 0
```

I always get ID2 = 0 !!, i don't know why the second parameter always evaluate to 0 !

Answer (score 4):

Or try that:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#define TAG "Java_my_package_MainActivity"
#define LOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, __VA_ARGS__)

// ...

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_my_package_MainActivity_getDistance(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong a_id1, jlong a_id2){

    // ...

    LOGI("ID1: %lu , ID2: %lu", a_id1, a_id2);
}
```

Comment: when passing down a final testLong = 256L from Java, I find that LOGI "%lu" prints different results from "%llu". @fadden answer may explain that.

Answer (score 2):

Your `sprintf` needs to use `%llu` to print a 64-bit quantity rather than `%u`.  I believe you're you're actually getting the correct values through JNI, but the `sprintf` call is being told to expect two 32-bit values and is printing the high word of the first argument.

Also, you should probably be using `jlong` in JNI declarations rather than your own custom type (it's defined in `jni.h`).